# Criar array de ServiceController dinamicamente

Tags: c#

Gostaria de criar um monitoramento de serviços do Windows e quero cadastrar uma quantidade customizável de serviços. Para isso preciso ter um array de ServiceController dinamicamente, o problema é que da Exception quando eu tento atribuir o nome do serviço à propriedade ServiceName.

Segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
//Eu declaro uma variável global
ServiceController[] scService;

//Aqui vai o código que busca os serviços e põe em um Array de String

//aí o contaService tem a quantidade de serviços cadastrados
scService = new ServiceController[contaService];

//Agora quando vou dar o nome aos servicos
for (int i = 0; i < contaService; i++)
{
    //Nessa linha da exception
    scService[i].ServiceName = scNome[i];
}
```

Comment: E Qual é o erro?

Comment: Olhando para o código provavelmente é erro de Null Excption, provavelmente esqueceu de atribuir ou instanciar o scService.

Comment: Sim, é NullReferenceException

Comment: @Ro_GEEK coloquei uma resposta logo abaixo, tenta usar no seu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce esqueceu de instanciar os vetores antes por isso está dando o Null Excption, tenta colocar isso antes:

```
scService[i] = new ServiceController("Simple Service");
```

Ou:

```
scService[i] = ServiceController.GetServices();
```

Comment: @KhaosDoctor eu fiz isso, o autor esclareu o erro, e minha resposta não deixa de estar correta..

Comment: Você me deu uma idéia boa. Pode ser considerada a resposta, sim!

Comment: Se for considerado avalie a pergunta =). Vlw e boa sorte.

Answer (score 1):

O correto é instanciar no laço For, passando os nomes como parâmetro para cada item do Array:

```
//Eu declaro uma variável global
ServiceController[] scService;

//Aqui vai o código que busca os serviços e põe em um Array

//Tira a linha que instancia array dos objetos vazios
//scService = new ServiceController[contaService];

//Agora quando vou dar o nome aos servicos
for (int i = 0; i < contaService; i++)
{
    //Alterei a linha da exception
    //scService[i].ServiceName = scNome[i];
    //Para a linha abaixo
    scService[i] = new ServiceController(scValor[i]);
}
```